# If/else statement and user dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a situation where I need the user to enter either a specific number (their monthly bill for example) or, in the case that they dont have a specific number, to choose from  a dropdown of averages by state. I am unsure how to write an if/else statement that firsts ask if the specific input is defined, and in lieu of a text input, to check for the dropdown value.

**Edit: this is my second attempt at getting something workable, no luck :/**

**JS**

```
    var val = document.getElementById('perKWhCost').value;
    var select_value = document.querySelector('#selection').value;
    var getMonthlyCost = function(){

        if (val){
            getMonthlyCost = val;
        }
        else{
            getMonthlyCost = select_value;
        }
        console.log(getMonthlyCost);
    }

    var getAnnualSavings = getMonthlyCost * finalAnnualEnergy;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label name="monthlyCost" for="inputKWh">Per kWh cost(see energy bill)</label>
            <p>This should look like "<em>$0.11/kWh</em>"</p>
            <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" id="perKWhCost" placeholder="0.11">
            <label for="state">Or select a state</label>
            <select name="Cost" id="selection">
              <option value=".11">Alabama</option>
              <option value=".19">Alaska</option>
              <option value=".11">Arizona</option>
              <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
              <option value="CA">California</option>
              <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
              <option value=".20">Connecticut</option>
              <option value=".13">Delaware</option>
              <option value=".13">District Of Columbia</option>
              <option value=".12">Florida</option>
              <option value=".11">Georgia</option>
              <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
              <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
              <option value=".11">Illinois</option>
              <option value=".11">Indiana</option>
              <option value=".11">Iowa</option>
              <option value=".12">Kansas</option>
              <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
              <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
              <option value=".18">Maine</option>
              <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
              <option value=".19">Massachusetts</option>
              <option value=".15">Michigan</option>
              <option value=".12">Minnesota</option>
              <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
              <option value=".09">Missouri</option>
              <option value="MT">Montana</option>
              <option value=".09">Nebraska</option>
              <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
              <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
              <option value=".16">New Jersey</option>
              <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
              <option value="NY">New York</option>
              <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
              <option value=".09">North Dakota</option>
              <option value=".12">Ohio</option>
              <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
              <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
              <option value=".14">Pennsylvania</option>
              <option value=".18">Rhode Island</option>
              <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
              <option value=".10">South Dakota</option>
              <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
              <option value="TX">Texas</option>
              <option value="UT">Utah</option>
              <option value=".17">Vermont</option>
              <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
              <option value="WA">Washington</option>
              <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
              <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
              <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
            </select>
          </div>


          <input type="button" value="Calculate!" id="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" onclick="doMath();">
        </form>
```

***Note: the JS above is part of the function doMath which is not fully shown here. Additionally, ignore that not every selection has a decimal value yet, that will be changed in the working code.***

This is the gist of what I need. I need to check if there is a value in the text field, if there is I want getMonthlyCost to store that value (preferably only if its a number). If there is no input in the text box I want the code to check the selector dropdown and take the users selection and pass that value to getMonthlyCost.

Comment: Your code has issues in html and js. See the red markers. Also, it seems to me you first want to check the text input, and if empty check the dropdown, but your script logic starts with first (attempt to) check the dropdown (js line 2). Also in your html you call a function that doesn't exist. I think you can do better.

Comment: please show your html and it would be better if you make a plnkr, other thing is "getMonthlyCost" is a function and you are using it like a variable. can you confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
var getMonthlyCost = function(){
    var val = document.getElementById('perKWhCost').value;
    var select_value = document.getElementById('selection');
    var parsedValue=parseFloat(val);//parse if user entered valid float or nothing
    if (parsedValue!=NaN & val!=""){// check parsed value
       return val;
    }
    else{
        if(select_value.selectedIndex != null) { //check if user has selected DropDown and get selected value if yes
        return select_value.options[select_value.selectedIndex].value;}
        else {//nothing entered}
    }
}

function doMath() {
    var getAnnualSavings = getMonthlyCost * 12;
    console.log(getAnnualSavings);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you assigned "getMonthlyCost" as a function and assumed it was not one in the call when trying to get the "getMonthlyCost". The code below should work

```
var getMonthlyCost = function(){
    var val = document.getElementById('perKWhCost').value;
    var select_value = document.querySelector('#selection').value;
    var returnValue = !!val ? val : select_value;
    console.log(returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}

var getAnnualSavings = getMonthlyCost() * finalAnnualEnergy;
```

Or you could do

```
var monthlyCost = document.getElementById("perKWCost").value || document.querySelector("#selection").value;
var annualSavings = monthlyCost * finalAnnualEnergy;
```

monthlyCost will take the take the first one if both are defined and if the first one is "", undefined or null, it will take the second one;

I hope this helps

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/12znp29s/

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()

Comment: The first one worked great! Thanks! And thank you to everyone who contributed, you're all amazing! May I ask _why_ it works? It appears that the variables store the user's potential input, then the function evaluates whether there is a text input, and if not, then returns the select_value. But what exactly does **!!var ? val : select_value;** do? The '!!' and '?' in particular.

Comment: Its an inline if statement

Comment: the !!val is to check if val is not null, undefined, "".... it works the same as if(val) but i use it to denote that val is not a bool.